# Where can i find template/phtml files of content pages in magento2 file structure?

Tags: content-management-system, magento2

I am trying to find as to where the content pages like homepage, about page, etc. which I make from admin>content>pages are stored in the magento2 file structure?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the template that is responsible for a specific part of the storefront or Admin, you can use Magento built-in template hints.
To enable template hints:

1. Click Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer.
2. In the Scope: dropdown in the upper-left corner select the view for which you want the template hints.
3. In the Debug tab, set Template Path Hints for storefront to Yes. To enable path hints for Admin set Template Path Hints for Admin to Yes.
4. To save the changes, click Save Config in the upper-right corner.

Document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html